# [Swift 2.2]: analog arc4random for range with negative numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, random, swift2

I wrote a function that finds the greatest difference among all elements of the array. But I need the restriction on the input elements array [-5..20]. Unfortunately it does not support UInt32. What are similar to a solution to fill the array randomly from the range [-5..20]?Thank you!

```
func highDifferenceV ( n: Int) ->String{
        var a = [Int]() //array
        var dif = 0     // max difference
        var k = 0


        for _ in 0..<n {
            a.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(20)))) // fill array


        }
        while k < a.count {  //search the greatest difference
            for i in 0..<n {
                if a[k] - a[i] > dif {
                    dif = a[k] - a[i]
                }
            }
            k++
        }
        print(a)
        return "Maximum difference =\(dif)"
    }

    highDifferenceV(75)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fill an array with values from `-5...20`, generate an number in the range `0...25` and then subtract `5`:

```
for _ in 0..<n {
    a.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(26)))-5) // fill array
}
```

In general, to generate a value in the range `min...max`, call `arc4random_uniform` with `max - min + 1` and then add `min`.